# What happens if you don't close a URL connection?

Tags: java, inputstream

What exactly happens when you don't close the below input stream?

```
InputStream is = new URL(queryUrl).openStream();
```

Since it's a URL connection, would it be smart enough to close automatically after request?

I tried looking at the documentation, but it is pretty vague. From what we gather, this is the same as doing `HTTPUrlConnection.getInputStream()`.

I'm just trying to figure out the impacts of not doing `is.close()`. Would this definitely cause resource leaks?

Comment: Yes. It will leak sockets until the program terminates then the OS will reclaim them.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `close`, associated system resources are released. If you look at implementation of method `URL.openStream()`

```
public final InputStream openStream() throws java.io.IOException {
   return openConnection().getInputStream();
}
public URLConnection openConnection() throws java.io.IOException {
   return handler.openConnection(this);
}
```

It returns a `URLConnection`, according to javadoc

> Invoking the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an URLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance, unless particular protocol specifications specify different behaviours for it.

As an example if you see [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), their docs say:

> Calling the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an HttpURLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance but has no effect on any shared persistent connection. Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

Cheers !!